# How to get a function (def) output in a data frame in python and merge multiple data frames

Tags: python

I have this code that calculates max drawdown using stock prices.

```
#max drawdown function code...
def max_drawdown(X):
    mdd = 0
    peak = X[0]
    for x in X:
        if x > peak: 
            peak = x
        dd = (x - peak) / peak
        if dd < mdd
            mdd = dd

    return mdd
```

I use the following function to show the drawdown

```
#shows max drawdown
stocks_prices.xs(key='close',axis=1,level='Stock Info').apply(max_drawdown)
```

Incase you want to see the head of stock prices it is

```
Ticker  NOW BBY NOW Return  BBY Return
Stock Info  open    high    low close   volume  open    high    low close   volume      
date                                                
2013-09-30  52.10   52.34   51.170  51.95   1383145 31.9605 32.3721 31.8061 32.1577 3826963 NaN NaN
2013-10-01  51.60   51.89   50.610  51.49   1288635 32.2092 32.7923 32.1834 32.5436 3607267 -0.008855   0.012000
2013-10-02  51.35   52.42   51.215  52.27   1158196 32.2606 32.4750 31.9005 32.2949 2990664 0.015149    -0.007642
2013-10-03  52.39   52.90   51.560  52.15   1512797 32.4236 32.5093 31.6089 32.3206 3413673 -0.002296   0.000796
2013-10-04  53.09   55.46   52.810  54.43   1688824 32.3206 32.9724 31.9862 32.7151 3311713 0.043720    0.012206
```

and the output is

```
Ticker
NOW   -0.476164
BBY   -0.485378
dtype: float64
```

since the calculation is inside a function, how do i input the output in a data frame. i am not able to use the following code to create a data frame, from the output of drawdown function

```
mdd = mdd.to_frame('Maximum Drawdown')
mdd.index.name = 'Ticker'
mdd = mdd.reset_index()
```

I have some multiple data frames like

```
 Ticker    Sharpe
0    NOW  8.061887
1    BBY  7.174034

Ticker    Var
0    NOW  -0.1
1    BBY  0.2
```

How do i merge all these data frames into one so can export to excel starting with ticker then values

so for example, i want the output as

```
Ticker    Var   Sharpe Ratio
    0    NOW  -0.1 0.5
    1    BBY  0.2 0.3
```

please help on both the things, really appreciate it

Comment: For joining DataFrames together - have you seen [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) ?

Comment: Thanks jamesj629. Will look at it. Any pointers on the other part?

Comment: It’s not really clear what your max_drawdown function is doing - can you adjust the formatting?

Comment: Hi James, thanks for pointing out the formatting error. Please let me know if you can give any pointers on creating the data frame (similar to other i have created) for drawdown function

Answer (score 0):

So starting with your code:

```
mdd = stocks_prices.xs(key='close',axis=1,level='Stock Info').apply(max_drawdown)
```

The `mdd` Series looks like:

```
Ticker
NOW   -0.008855
BBY   -0.007642
dtype: float64
```

you may have different numbers.

Not sure if you want that in `stocks_prices` or not - if you do, this is how:

The easiest way is by creating a new column

```
stocks_prices[ 'NOW mdd' ] = float('NaN')
```

and get the last day in the DataFrame:

```
last_day = stocks_prices.index[-1]
```

which for me is `2013-10-04` but I think you had more rows. Anyway, stick that into the last row of the column `NOW mdd`:

```
stocks_prices.loc[ last_day, 'NOW mdd' ] = mdd[ 'NOW' ]
```

so my `stocks_prices` looks like:

```
Ticker        NOW                       BBY                    NOW Return BBY Return   NOW mdd
Stock Info   open high  low  close     open high  low    close
2013-09-30  50.95  NaN  NaN  51.95  31.1577  NaN  NaN  32.1577        NaN        NaN       NaN
2013-10-01  50.49  NaN  NaN  51.49  31.5436  NaN  NaN  32.5436  -0.008855   0.012000       NaN
2013-10-02  51.27  NaN  NaN  52.27  31.2949  NaN  NaN  32.2949   0.015149  -0.007642       NaN
2013-10-03  51.15  NaN  NaN  52.15  31.3206  NaN  NaN  32.3206  -0.002296   0.000796       NaN
2013-10-04  53.43  NaN  NaN  54.43  31.7151  NaN  NaN  32.7151   0.043720   0.012206 -0.008855
```

### Merging

Putting DataFrames together is normally done on a common key like `Ticker`.

So a `sharpe` DataFrame:

```
     Sharpe Ticker
0  8.061887    NOW
1  7.174034    BBY
```

and a `var` DataFrame:

```
  Ticker  Var
0    NOW -0.1
1    BBY  0.2
```

can be merged with

```
result = sharpe.merge( var, on='Ticker', suffixes=('','') )
```

giving

```
     Sharpe Ticker  Var
0  8.061887    NOW -0.1
1  7.174034    BBY  0.2
```

If we want to merge `mdd` into that we can turn `mdd` into a DataFrame first:

```
result2 = result.merge( mdd.to_frame('mdd'), on='Ticker', suffixes=('','') )
```

giving

```
     Sharpe Ticker  Var       mdd
0  8.061887    NOW -0.1 -0.008855
1  7.174034    BBY  0.2 -0.007642
```

### Continuous max drawdown

btw you can can change you `max_drawdown` function sightly to output a list e.g.

```
def max_drawdown2(X):
    mdd = 0
    peak = X[0]
    values = []  # <-- NEW LINE
    for x in X:
        if x > peak: 
            peak = x
        dd = (x - peak) / peak
        if dd < mdd:
            mdd = dd
        values.append( mdd )  # <-- NEW LINE

    return values   # <-- NEW LINE

stocks_prices[ 'NOW mdd' ] = max_drawdown2( stocks_prices.loc[ :, ('NOW','close') ] )
```

to get

```
Ticker        NOW                       BBY                    NOW Return BBY Return   NOW mdd
Stock Info   open high  low  close     open high  low    close
2013-09-30  50.95  NaN  NaN  51.95  31.1577  NaN  NaN  32.1577        NaN        NaN  0.000000
2013-10-01  50.49  NaN  NaN  51.49  31.5436  NaN  NaN  32.5436  -0.008855   0.012000 -0.008855
2013-10-02  51.27  NaN  NaN  52.27  31.2949  NaN  NaN  32.2949   0.015149  -0.007642 -0.008855
2013-10-03  51.15  NaN  NaN  52.15  31.3206  NaN  NaN  32.3206  -0.002296   0.000796 -0.008855
2013-10-04  53.43  NaN  NaN  54.43  31.7151  NaN  NaN  32.7151   0.043720   0.012206 -0.008855
```

Notice that `.loc[ :, ('NOW','close') ]` is using `:` get all the dates and then `('NOW','close')` is getting by `Ticker` and then `Stock Info` level

The same `(Ticker, close)` syntax could have been used to add a subcolumn instead:

```
stocks_prices[ ('NOW', 'mdd' ) ] = max_drawdown2( stocks_prices.loc[ :, ('NOW','close') ] )
```

Comment: Thanks james, worked fine. was able to calculate daily drawdown as well. Would you know how to calculate the cagr as well? so basically for close value for each stock           = it should be (last/start)^ (365/length of column) - 1

Comment: I can look a bit later but  stocks_prices.index[-1] is the last index, stocks_prices.index[0] would be the first index - have a go at it - all you need is in the above

Comment: `stocks_prices.xs( key='close', axis=1, level='Stock Info' ).apply( lambda s: (s.iloc[-1] / s.iloc[0])**(365.0/len(s) ) )`